# GameLit style story, Fighting zombies in a skyscraper apartment building from the top down, and leveling up rank

Tags: story-identification, zombie, litrpg

Read in the last year, probably not more than a few years old. Its either a GameLit novel, (Hero fights the monsters and levels up, and gets new stats and skills) Or a Fan Fiction story published on a story site.

Guy wakes up in about the 100th floor of an apartment tower and finds he has a Hud telling him he has to kill x zombies to complete level 1, and has xx minutes before they break down his door and he has to fight them.

Killing them yields XP (and on higher level zombies, monster cores, which he has to collect from the bodies)

Using random junk in his apartment he is able to kill the zombies when they break down the door. In addition to the kill xx zombies on each floor quests, he is given "rescue" quests.
His first is to save a woman in a neighboring apartment. (xx minutes to save her before the zombies break in her door) Also "daily" quests such as exercise. (do 100 pushups, sit-ups, run 1 mile etc.)

One "cheat" he discovers, is when he sees lots of zombies clustered around the base of the tower, he starts dropping appliances, furniture, tools, flower pots, anything heavy to crush the zombies on the ground. This gives him a BIG boost to his XP gain.

There is a "Store" in his HUD where he can choose his new skills. One that he is able to get early is Time manipulation. (Slow time for fighting, and speed up time for himself, so he regains energy quickly, or sleeps 8 hours in a few minutes)

By absorbing the monster cores he is able to boost his stats and abilities. Also everyone (else?) is slowly being zombified (xx days) and will eventually turn into a mindless zombie like the ones he is killing. BUT if he gets other people (that he rescued) to absorb the cores, they become zombified in another fashion, and are immune to becoming mindless. (IIRC, the girl gets much stronger and tougher skin) and as those companions level up from kills, he can level their skills and stats.

By the time they get to about the 20th floor? He has rescued about 50 people? But has only made 3-4 companions by having them absorb cores. He is by now (from droppings things from windows and balconies) about 10x stronger/faster/tougher than his companions, and 100x stronger/faster/tougher than a normal person.

At about the 20th floor the normal people have built a barriers in the stairwells and want to hole up and eat what food they have collected and hope for rescue. So he bypasses the barrier and starts soloing the remaining floors a few at a time while everyone else sleeps.

The zombies are ranked like your typical GameLit ranking. Starting with E rank weaklings, D rank speedsters, C rank who can eat other zombies and level themselves up, to A rank in the bottom floors of the tower.

Pretty sure the story ends when he reaches the ground floor, and has to decide to proceed to another tower and continue fighting, or enter the basement and fight something very powerful that is down there.

Comment: *Reborn: Apocalypse* partially matches as well, although the main character is brought in from another world, rather than waking up in the situation.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Nope I checked it. Found a site listing all the chapters and it is not Reborn: Apocalypse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. (Although I don't know how this cover is supposed to relate. No one is dressed like that, there is no magic and I don't recall any harem aspects, The MC is a virgin until about the last few chapters. Its much more GameLIT than HaremLIT)

The book is called [**Zombie Apocalypse Harem**](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/75719143-zombie-apocalypse-harem) by Abraham Mendez

[image]

Guy wakes up in about the 100th floor of an apartment tower and finds he has a Hud telling him he has to kill x zombies to complete level 1, and has xx minutes before they break down his door and he has to fight them.

> He actually lives on the 64th floor
>
> [Emergency Quest: Survive the Zombie Horde for the next 5 hours. Total
> Numbers of Zombies remaining:8. Zombies will break into your house in
> 59 minutes 59 seconds]

He is given "rescue" quests. His first is to save a woman in a neighboring apartment. (xx minutes to save her before the zombies break in her door) Also "daily" quests such as exercise. (do 100 pushups, sit-ups, run 1 mile etc.)

> [Quests: Side Quests: Save the Survivor Trapped in the Guest Room]
>
> [Quests: Daily Quests]
>
> [1. Survive to the end of the Day: 40 minutes remaining till dawn]
>
> [2. Push ups: 0/10]
>
> [3. Walk: 146/1000 Steps]
>
> [4. Drink 2 Liters of Water: 0/2L]

One "cheat" he discovers, is when he sees lots of zombies clustered around the base of the tower, he starts dropping appliances, furniture, tools, flower pots, anything heavy to crush the zombies on the ground. This gives him a BIG boost to his XP gain.

> I looked down once again and smiled before… dropping the heavy weights
> down from the balcony. 'Please hit!' [Ding!] [You have killed a Lesser
> E-grade Zombie]

Pretty sure the story ends when he reaches the ground floor, and has to decide to proceed to another tower and continue fighting, or enter the basement and fight something very powerful that is down there.

> In the end he has 2 side quests:
>
> [Side Quest: Free the area from zombies!] *(The Parking lot and
> surrounding park)*
>
> [Side Quest: Clear the basement!] [Something unholy
> has taken birth within the basement. If it evolves any further, it may
> bring doom to the surviving mankind.]

The only thing I miss remembered is the Zombie levels.. He never faces anything but Lesser and Normal E & D Grade Zombies. Although his next advancement requires killing C-Grade Zombies. (Whom he would obviously discover in the basement quest or outside in the parking lot quest.)

Answer (score 1):

Might it be *[Blood for Power](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/65675/blood-for-power-litrpg-dungeon-tower-apocalypse)* by ScottJames?

> For Lucas, it came as quite a shock when he woke up to find the world had ended. The System had taken over and transformed his apartment building into a 100-floor dungeon tower of traps, monsters, and loot. The residents have just one year to reach the ground floor and escape before the tower self-destructs.
>
> That’s his first problem.
>
> The second is that he slept through the System’s welcome orientation and class selection process, so the System picked a class for him. Lucas is now a Blood Reaver. A class based on speed, ferocity, and striking from the shadows. He’s expected not just to defeat his enemies but to slaughter them and bathe in their blood. Their blood is now his power.
>
> Outraged at being invaded, Lucas vows to grow stronger and take back his world. He will not only survive but *thrive* as he carves a bloody path to the very pinnacle of power.

Found with a search for `litrpg zombies "apartment building"`

Comment: After a bit more reading, I haven't found the references to zombies that were indicated by it popping up on the search terms, so it seems less likely this is the one, but leaving it here as a partial answer.

Comment: Nope this is not the one. Very similar setting, but the 1 year time limit was the first thing to make me think no. Many of the features were similar (such as a HUD description of the kitchen knife) but as you pointed out. No Zombies. (pretty sure in the story they only had to fight zombies, no other creatures.) Also this looks like its currently a "work in progress". (only been up for a couple weeks) What I read was a completed story.